# nicematrix — override column separator @{} in \Block

Tags: nicematrix

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{r@{---}l}
1 & 2 \\
10 & 20 \\
\Block{1-2}{100}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

produces this table

[image]

The problem is that column separator `@{---}` is still present in multicolumn created with `\Block` which overlaps the content. Is it possible to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Try the legacy `\multicolumn` command instead

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{r@{---}l}
        1 & 2 \\
        10 & 20 \\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{100}
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```